# Substitution in this laplace integral, how the orignal complex variable becomes a real variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, substitution

I'm learning cagniard de-hoop method(*de Hoop, A. T.*, [**A modification of Cagniard’s method for solving seismic pulse problems**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02920068), Appl. Sci. Res. B 8, 349-356 (1960). [ZBL0100.44208](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0100.44208).), but I don't quit understand the derivation of some formulas in it.

In Eq.(2.12)

> $U(x,y;s)=\frac{F(s)}{2\pi i}\int^{i\infty}_{-i\infty}exp[-s(px+\eta|y|)]\frac{1}{2\eta}dp\tag{2.12}$

in which

> $\eta=(1/v^2-p^2)^{1/2} (Re\ge 0)\tag{2.13}$

p is a complex variable in the p-plane, the only singularities of the integrand in Eq(2.12) are branch points at $p=1/v$ and $p=-1/v$. In view of subsequent deformations of the path of integration we take $Re (\eta)\ge 0$ everywhere in p-plane. This implies that branch cuts are introduced along $Im(p)=0$, $1/v<|Re(p)|<\infty$

The next step towards the solution of the transient problem is to perform the integration in the p-plane along such a path that the right-hand side of (2.12) can be recognized as the Laplace transform of a certain function of time. The analysis which follows will show
that the path has to be selected such that

> $px+\eta|y|=\tau\tag{2.14}$

which $\tau$ is real and positive

I konw the certain function of time is real and positive, but why is $px+\eta|y|=\tau$ real and positive? In other words, why is $px+\eta|y|$ the certain function of time.